# can't change orientation of ViewController in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, screen-orientation, xcode-storyboard

I need to change the orientation in storyboard but it doesn't change

Here is where i change it

[image]

And also how to set only portrait mode for the whole app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

choose iphone 3.5 inch in size and then it will rotate
and you can set only portrait mode by setting general settings of your xcode project in which check only that device orientation which you want

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked exactly as you mentioned. Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year

Answer (score 1):

Go To Target --> General and set Orientation Mode to Portrait.

[image]

Comment: i found it thanks. I'm android developer so i don't know much about xcode. sorry for stupid question

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the view controller's Simulated Metrics -> Size -> Inferred. I had it on Freeform that disabled landscape.

[image]